# Start new Whatsapp chat Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I am working on a project where i have an excel file with many numbers and I want to send message to each number on whatsapp using automation of course. I an taking numbers from the file one by one and trying to send message using whatsapp direct message link, the problem is that there can be some numbers which are not register on whatsapp, in that case the whatsapp web displays a message that 'this number is not valid'. To skip this number and move to the next one I am checking if the message in present or not. if it is present then close the message box and take the next number, if message box is not present then just send the message to the number.

the problem is that the if condition i am using to check for the existence of the message box sometimes runs 2 time, sometime 4 some time 14, i mean it is running random times i dont know why. Sometime it return false even the number is registered on whatsapp. bellow is my code please help me guys.

```
df = PD.read_excel(excel_path)
number = df['number'].tolist()
for i in number:
    contact = f'https://wa.me/{str(i)}'
    driver.get(contact)

    #check if number appears in header( that means chat is open and number exist on whatsapp
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/header/div[2]/div/div/span'))!=0):       

        time.sleep(3)   
        chat_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')))
        for msg in msgs:
            chat_box.send_keys(msg)
            chat_box.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,'\n')
        chat_box.send_keys("\n")   
        print(f'Message sent to {str(i)}') 
        time.sleep(3)  
        count+=1 
        print(f'{count} messages sent')

    # check if message box appears( means number is not available on whatsapp.
    # so close the message box and take next number
    elif (len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div'))!=0):
        print(f'{str(i)} not found') 
        time.sleep(3)
        alert = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div')))
        alert.click()

      # number is not on whatsapp
      # so close the message box and take next number
    else:     
        print(f'{str(i)} not found') 
        time.sleep(3)
        alert = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div')))
        alert.click()
```

Comment: what is in number  variable , print that value

Comment: I am taking that number from excel file using pandas. they are all valid mobile numbers but many of them are not registered on whatsapp

Comment: why do ypu think if condition going multiple time ?

Comment: df[number] is the column heading and all numbers are under that heading. tolist() method will take the number one by one

Comment: only way the if condition to run multiple time for same number is tolist() to have duplicate entry

Comment: because i have checked that, sometimes it stuck after 5 iterations sometime after 2. it is so rendom

Comment: please add the stack trace , where is it getting stuck

Comment: no brother all are unique numbers, i myself have entered them

Comment: the if condition run correctly only once, after that it always jumps to else part i even if the header element i am checking inside if() is present dont know why